# How I get a Scrollbar for My ListView control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, html, scrollbar

I have built a ASP.NET Application and use two divs and a ListView. My ListView get Data from a Database and if I have to much Rows a I get a overflow but I want then a Scrollbar for this ListView.

My Site:

[image]

My Site if I have to much rows :(

[image]

My Site with a Scrollbar that I want!

[image]

My Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="lw_content" runat="server">
    <div class="userlist">
        <div class="liste">

            <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="myListView">

                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table id="UserList" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr style="background-color:#ccdaeb">
                            <th align="left">
                                <asp:Label ID="header_name" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label></th>
                            <th align="left">
                                <asp:Label ID="header_firma" runat="server" Text="Firma"></asp:Label></th>
                            <th align="left">
                                <asp:Label ID="header_von" runat="server" Text="gültig ab"></asp:Label></th>
                            <th align="left">
                                <asp:Label ID="header_bis" runat="server" Text="gültig bis"></asp:Label></th>
                            <th align="left">
                                <asp:Label ID="header_ersteller" runat="server" Text="erstellt von"></asp:Label></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="lblname" Text='<%# Eval("GanzerName") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="lblfirma" Text='<%# Eval("Firma") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="lblvon" Text='<%# Eval("GültigVon") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="lblbis" Text='<%# Eval("GültigBis") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="lblersteler" Text='<%# Eval("Ersteller") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>

                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <h4>Es wurden keine Einträge gefunden</h4><br/>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAnlegen" Text="Benutzer Anlegen"/>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>

                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="lblname" Text='<%# Eval("GanzerName") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="lblfirma" Text='<%# Eval("Firma") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="lblvon" Text='<%# Eval("GültigVon") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="lblbis" Text='<%# Eval("GültigBis") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                        <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="lblersteler" Text='<%# Eval("Ersteller") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                    </tr>
                </AlternatingItemTemplate>

            </asp:ListView>

        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix the hsight if liste div and set [**overflow**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) to visible or what ever suits you. Height must be less then the height taken by data in side div to see the scroll bar.

Change

```
 <div class="liste">
```

to

```
<div class="liste" style="height:300px; overflow:scroll">
```

or

```
<div class="liste" style="height:300px; overflow:visible">
```

Comment: You need vertical scroll bar ? height must be less then the height taken by data and try overflow:scroll, I should work

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the overflow to scroll:

```
<div class="liste" style="height:200px; overflow:scroll;">
```